# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'NAME' in 'where clause'

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jdbc, glassfish

I recently set the Logger Settings better in my Glassfish. Now I have MySQL errors, because I use JPA, I don't know how to fix this errors. All similar questions react with SQL statements and because my JPA I needed a better solution than a SQL query. I need it to use the jdbcrealm security from glassfish

The error that I get:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'NAME' in 'where clause'

Do you need my classes to fix this? or my tables? I can try to supply all info needed.

full stack:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'NAME' in 'where clause'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.PreparedStatementWrapper40.executeQuery(PreparedStatementWrapper40.java:642)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm.findGroups(JDBCRealm.java:514)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:325)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.login.JDBCLoginModule.authenticate(JDBCLoginModule.java:78)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.PasswordLoginModule.authenticateUser(PasswordLoginModule.java:116)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.BasePasswordLoginModule.login(BasePasswordLoginModule.java:146)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor70.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:784)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:698)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:695)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:594)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:383)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:241)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:154)
at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:695)
at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:636)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.processSecurityCheck(AuthenticatorBase.java:991)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:580)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:702)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gebruiker")
public class User implements Serializable  {

@Id  //@Column(name="User_NAME")
private String name;
```

And this is the bean who adds the users:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class InitBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * Creates a new instance of InitBean
 */
@Inject
private UserDAO userDAO;

public InitBean() {
}

@PostConstruct
public void initUsers() {
    Role rol1 = new Role("admin");
    Role rol2 = new Role("gebruiker");
    User u1 = new User("Hans", "http", "geboren 1", "Eindhoven", sha256("Hans"), rol1);
    User u2 = new User("Frank", "httpF", "geboren 2", "Best", sha256("Frank"), rol1);
    User u3 = new User("Tom", "httpT", "geboren 3", "Geldrop", sha256("Tom"), rol1);
    User u4 = new User("Sjaak", "httpS", "geboren 4", "Son", sha256("Sjaak"), rol1);

    u1.addFollowing(u2);
    u1.addFollowing(u3);
    u1.addFollowing(u4);

    Tweet t1 = new Tweet("Hallo", new Date(), "PC");
    Tweet t2 = new Tweet("Hallo again", new Date(), "PC");
    Tweet t3 = new Tweet("Hallo where are you", new Date(), "PC");
    u1.addTweet(t1);
    u1.addTweet(t2);
    u1.addTweet(t3);
    rol1.addGebruiker(u1);
    rol1.addGebruiker(u2);
    rol1.addGebruiker(u3);
    rol1.addGebruiker(u4);

    userDAO.addRole(rol1);
    userDAO.addRole(rol2);

    userDAO.create(u1);
    userDAO.create(u2);
    userDAO.create(u3);
    userDAO.create(u4);
}
```

And this is the userDAO:

```
public interface UserDAO {

void create(User user);
```

And this is the userDAOJPA:

```
@Alternative
@Stateless
public class UserDAOJPA implements UserDAO {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "KwetterPU")
private EntityManager em;

 private List<User> users= new ArrayList();
public UserDAOJPA() {
}

@Override
public void create(User user) {
    users.add(user);
    em.persist(user);
}
```

New Stack trace if I change nAME to User_NAME:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'User_NAME' in 'field list'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.PreparedStatementWrapper40.executeQuery(PreparedStatementWrapper40.java:642)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm.findGroups(JDBCRealm.java:514)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:325)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.login.JDBCLoginModule.authenticate(JDBCLoginModule.java:78)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.PasswordLoginModule.authenticateUser(PasswordLoginModule.java:116)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.BasePasswordLoginModule.login(BasePasswordLoginModule.java:146)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor70.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:784)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:698)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:695)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:594)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:383)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:241)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:154)
at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:695)
at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:636)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.processSecurityCheck(AuthenticatorBase.java:991)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:580)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:702)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

!http://s29.postimg.org/u6lgsjto7/User_NAME.png

Comment: If you could show us the lines of code immediately around the line that the exception was thrown on, that would help.

Comment: Hello Rudi, As it happens when I want to use the security jdbc realm from glassfish, I'm not sure which line of code is the reason of the error, but I added the full stack, I hope it helps. please tell me if I can find the line of could another way or you need other information

Comment: Ah, I see. That's a very unfortunately unhelpful stack trace you've been given.

Comment: Post your `Constructor.java` class. How we help you?

Comment: @CycDemo: You mean the constructor of my Java class related to the NAME column? I added the script to my question, is that enough to help you? or do you need all properties of the script? (the Column name User_NAME I think is needed but as I then have 2 tables with the same column and that makes the error even harder)

Comment: @CycDemo: I added all classes I could think would help you.

Comment: @RudiKershaw Is there a way to make the stacktrace more helpful?

Comment: On your user class you have `//@Column(name="User_NAME")` commented out but the name of the variable is not the same. The variable is `Unknown column 'NAME'` which might refer to that `name` variable. Maybe uncomment that line and see if it changes the exception. You might need to define which column `name` refers to.